# Running a list of functions with different params with a single command

Tags: r, classification, multicore, svm, nnet

I am looking to test outcome of different regression/classification algorithms (i.e. svm, nnet, rpart, randomForest, naiveBayes, etc.) on the same data, to see which works better. But I need to have my code as short and clean as possible. To test all algorithms, I want to run them using a single `mclapply()` call of package `multicore`:

```
invisible(lapply(c("party","nnet","caret","klaR","randomForest","e1071","rpart",
                   "multicore"), require, character.only = T))
algorithms <- c(knn3, NaiveBayes, nnet, ctree, randomForest, svm, naiveBayes, rpart)
data(iris)
model <- mclapply(algorithms, function(alg) alg(Species ~ ., iris))
```

The problem is that some of the algorithms need extra parameters, i.e. `nnet()` needs parameter `size` to be set. For sure this can be fixed through several `if,else` commands, but is there any simpler solution?

Comment: You can try replacing `nnet` with a wrapper: `algorithms[[3]] <- function(...) nnet(...,size=your_size)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do is replace those in `algorithms` that require additional arguments with partial functions, e.g.

```
algorithms <- c(knn3, ctree, function(...) nnet(..., size=2))
```

Comment: Equivalently, with the `functional` package, you can use `Curry(nnet, size=2)` as the function.

Comment: It's a great solution. I am thinking if we can easily assign names of algorithms to `names()` of `mclapply()` result, without extra variable definition: i.e. `alg.names <- c("knn3",...`

Comment: @BrianDiggs aha, `Curry`! I knew this was out there somewhere.

Comment: @Ali atomic vectors accept names, so you could do `c(knn3=knn3, nnet=function(...) nnet(..., 2), etc.)`. I can't recall if `mclapply` will preserve those names, but you could use `names(model) <- names(algorithms)`, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Package `multicore` does not seem to be available for Windows, but here's one way, with a simple example with ordinary `lapply`:

```
# names of the functions as strings
algorithms <- c("lm", "glm")
# arguments for each function (empty list for those which do not need any)
arguments <- list(lm=list(model=FALSE),glm=list(family = gaussian),lm=list())

# Use lapply with do.call
output<-lapply(1:length(algorithms), function(i) do.call(what=algorithms[i],
                    args=c(list(formula=y ~ .,data=freeny),arguments[[i]])))
names(output)<-algorithms #Add names to output
```

Now list `output` contains the outputs from each algorithm. Note that at first look the outputs (by command `output$lm`) of this example look bit awful as the printing of `lm` and `glm` shows the function call along with summary, and the function call is quite long here.

edit: Some small tweaking.